# Prove the number of arrangements is equal to $\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Considering $n$ distinct elements, and an ordered set of $j$ elements (without repetitions); Example: $(a,b,c)$, $n=3$, $j=2$, there are 6 arrangements possible; $(ab,ac,ba,bc,ca,cb)$

I have to prove that the number of arrangements is equal to $$\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}$$

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for the first choice we have $n$ options, for the second $n-1$ and so on. Evnetually the number of combinations would be:

$$n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-j+1) = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots 1}{(n-j)(n-j-1)\cdots 1} = \frac{n!}{(n-j)!}$$